# slideUp and slideDown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-animate, jquery-load

I have a table in which I can click the rows () with the class `.details`. This will show a div with `id="details"` with extra information about the element in the row.

I have the following code.

```
$('.details').click(function () {
    $('#details').slideUp('slow');
    $('#details').load($(this).data('url'), { id: $(this).data('id') }, function () {
        $(this).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

However I would like the loading (`.load()`) to happen after the `.slideUp()` due to the fact that the load starts while the element is sliding up (which looks wierd). I have tried to add it as a callback function the following way:

```
$('#details').slideUp('slow', function () {
    $('#details').load($(this).data('url'), { id: $(this).data('id') }, function () {
        $(this).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

However that stops the code from working. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

## EDIT:

My table row looks as follows:

```
<tr class="details" data-id="@item.VehicleID" data-url="@Url.Action("Details", "Vehicle")">
</tr>
```

My div looks as follows:

```
<div id="details"></div>
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you sure you have any other js errors in your page ? check your browser console

Comment: No errors in the console and this piece of code is the only in my script.

Comment: Are you saying the slideup is not working even ?

Comment: Well, nothing happens at all when using the 2nd piece of code I posted. It worked when I had the 1st piece of code..

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code to a local page and it worked fine for me

Comment: How did you construct your `<div id="details"></div>`? Just like here?

Comment: `<div id="details" data-url="/Home/Add" data-id="1"></div>`

Comment: It looks like you use the same ID `#details`multiple times in your table. If so, don't do that. [An ID have to be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html). Probably jQuery can't handle multiple elements with same ID. But I don't know whether this is the reason for your problem.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch. There is only one element with the `id="details"`. However the `class="details"` I have many of.

Comment: @Shyju Could it have something to do with the way my div or table row are constructed? Please see my edit.

Comment: do you have the div with id details inside a loop ?

Comment: Nopes. I don't.. There is only 1 element in my entire page with the id="details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem i see with your code is, you are using   `$(this).data('url')` to get the url data attribute value set to the tr which was clicked. but `$(this)` is actually the `$('#details')` there because you are accessing it inside the slideUp of `$('#details')`, which does not have the url data attribute. So you must be getting an error

The solution is to assign the `$(this`) (clicked row) to a local variable and use that inside your other callback function.

This should work.

```
$(function () {


    $('.details').click(function () {
        var _this = $(this);

        $('#details').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $('#details').load(_this.data('url'), { id: _this.data('id') }, function () {
                $('#details').slideDown('slow');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be something like this. Could it be done by using "parent" in any way? I do however think this is the cleanest solution

Comment: You can use parent  method, but if you introduce another DOM element in between the code will break. So i think reading and storing to local variable is a good idea. or you can read the url and id value from $(this) before you do the slideUp call, store in a local variable and use that.